# Symfony 2 EntityManager injection in service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I've created my own service and I need to inject doctrine EntityManager, but I don't see that `__construct()` is called on my service, and injection doesn't work.

Here is the code and configs:

```
<?php

namespace Test\CommonBundle\Services;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class UserService {

    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager 
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __constructor(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        var_dump($entityManager);
        exit(); // I've never saw it happen, looks like constructor never called
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getUser($userId){
       var_dump($this->em ); // outputs null  
    }

}
```

Here is `services.yml` in my bundle

```
services:
  test.common.userservice:
    class:  Test\CommonBundle\Services\UserService
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

I've imported that .yml in `config.yml` in my app like that

```
imports:
    # a few lines skipped, not relevant here, i think
    - { resource: "@TestCommonBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

And when I call service in controller

```
    $userservice = $this->get('test.common.userservice');
    $userservice->getUser(123);
```

I get an object (not null), but `$this->em` in UserService is null, and as I already mentioned, constructor on UserService has never been called

One more thing, Controller and UserService are in different bundles (I really need that to keep project organized), but still: everyting else works fine, I can even call

```
$this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
```

in same controller that I use to get UserService and get valid (not null) EntityManager object.

Look like that I'm missing piece of configuration or some link between UserService and Doctrine config.

Comment: Have you tried setter injection? It works?

Comment: If by 'setter injection' you mean add in setter method for EntityManager on my service and calling in controller with $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager') as parameter, then yes, i've tried and it works. But i really like to use proper injection via config

Comment: I mean this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection anyway `__constructor` is the error.

Comment: Um, than i haven't tried setter injection. __construct fixed the problem, but anyways, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Your class's constructor method should be called `__construct()`, not `__constructor()`:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Hi, in this example, how could I change the connection from default to any other?

Comment: Right, but it would be even better if you used an interface. `public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)`

Answer (score 65):

For modern reference, in Symfony 2.4+, you cannot name the arguments for the Constructor Injection method anymore. According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html) You would pass in:

```
services:
    test.common.userservice:
        class:  Test\CommonBundle\Services\UserService
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

And then they would be available in the order they were listed via the arguments (if there are more than 1).

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: You can do a:
app/console container:debug
And find out what services you are running as well.

Answer (score 18):

Note as of Symfony 3.3 EntityManager is depreciated. Use EntityManagerInterface instead.

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Someclass {
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function somefunction() {
        $em = $this->em;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this and is confused: the EntityManager has certainly not been depreciated.  Using the interface helps with auto-wiring and is recommended but is by no means required.  And the interface has been around for a long time.  Nothing really new here.

Comment: This is the answer. However, please do reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154558/symfony2-3-better-way-to-get-entitymanager-inside-a-controller

Comment: Update to my own solution. The proper way now should be to use Entities and Repositories. Entity Manager is already naturally injected into a repository. You can see an example here: https://youtu.be/AHVtOJDTx0M

Answer (score 7):

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3** you can **register Repository as service**, with all its advantages it has.

**Check my post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)** for more general description.

---

To your specific case, original code with tuning would look like this:

#### 1. Use in your services or Controller

```
<?php

namespace Test\CommonBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class UserService
{
    private $userRepository;

    // use custom repository over direct use of EntityManager
    // see step 2
    public function __constructor(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function getUser($userId)
    {
        return $this->userRepository->find($userId);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Create new custom repository

```
<?php

namespace Test\CommonBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class UserRepository
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(UserEntity::class);
    }

    public function find($userId)
    {
        return  $this->repository->find($userId);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Register services

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    Test\CommonBundle\:
       resource: ../../Test/CommonBundle
```