# Inject EntityManagerInterface to my service with `must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface error`

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I have created a service at ./src/Service, and I want to use the Doctrine Entity Manager in my service, so I inject it in the `__construct` method:

namespace App\Service;

```
use App\Entity\Category;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Error\LoaderError;
use Twig\Error\RuntimeError;
use Twig\Error\SyntaxError;

class CommonPageGenerator
{
  /**
   * @var EntityManagerInterface
   */
  private $em;
  /**
   * @var Environment
   */
  private $templating;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Environment $templating)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->templating = $templating;
  }

  public function page1($title){ return; }

}
```

I then inject this service in a controller:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/overseas", name="overseas")
   * @param CommonPageGenerator $commonPageGenerator
   */
  public function overseas(CommonPageGenerator $commonPageGenerator)
  {
    return $commonPageGenerator->page1('overseas');
  }
```

But I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Service\CommonPageGenerator::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, string given, called in /Users/tangmonk/Documents/mygit/putixin.com/putixin_backend/var/cache/dev/ContainerB7I3rzx/getCommonPageGeneratorService.php on line 11

[image]

My `services.yaml` file:

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
          $em: 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
```

I am using Symfony 4.3

Comment: Basically you've to inject your dependency in your `services.yaml` file unless you are on Sf4.3+ (not sure if it does exists since then) and you're using `autowiring` Check [this post ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427282/symfony-2-entitymanager-injection-in-service) it has a bunch of useful information that could help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need binding `$em` to the Doctrine entity manager.

If you remove that line and leave the type hint only (`__construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Environment $templating`) should be enough.

Thus leaving your `__construct()` method like this:

```php
// you can of course import the EngineInterface with a "use" statement. 
public function __construct(
                    EntityManagerInterface $em,
                    Environment $templating)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->templating = $templating;
  }
```

If you do this and **remove** the bind configuration, automatic dependency injection should work by itself.

<sub>(Normally I would suggest replacing `Environment` with `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface`, to depend in the interface provided by the framework to integrate with the templating component. But [this component and its integration have been deprecated in 4.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-deprecated-the-templating-component-integration), and will be removed by 5.0; so you are fine by depending directly on Twig.)</sub>

But *if want to you leave the binding in place for some reason*, you should prefix the service name with an `@` symbol, so Symfony knows you are trying to inject a service and not string. Like so:

```
 bind:
          $em: '@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
```

[Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type).